# 401 (Unauthorized) only in release mode. Debugging, everything works perfectly! Why?

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension, twitter-oauth

I am creating an extension for Google Chrome and I'm having trouble authenticating with Twitter.

This extension is published in [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hcafjgmcknlklpddgpbbebbpbgcohgfn?hl=en-US&gl=BR):

As you can see, I am also consuming Dropbox API (which also works with OAuth 1.0) and it works perfectly!

To work with OAuth use a library called jsOAuth available at [this link](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth).

When the user clicks on the "Twitter", a window (popup) appears to be made ​​authentic:

```
//Request Windows token
chrome.windows.create({url: url, type:"popup"}, function(win){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.tabs[0].id, { file: "/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.tabs[0].id, { file: "/scripts/querystring-0.9.0-min.js" }, function() {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(this.args[0], { file: "/scripts/services/TwitterPage.js" });
        });
    });
});
```

url = _https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXX&oauth_token_secret=YYY&oauth_callback_confirmed=true_

### TwitterPage.js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#allow").click(function(){
        var token = $.QueryString("oauth_token");
        var secret = $.QueryString("oauth_token_secret");

        var data = { oauth_token: token, oauth_secret: secret };
        chrome.extension.sendRequest(data);
    });
});
```

Then the authentication window is displayed

[image: Request access window]

Full link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2s7D.png

As you can see in the above code, a request is sent to my extension.
Following is the code that captures this request:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.windows.remove(sender.tab.windowId, fetchAccessToken);
});
```

### fetchAccessToken function:

```
fetchAccessToken = function() {
    oauthObj.fetchAccessToken(function(){
            console.log("This code is only executed when debug step by step")
        }, failureHandler);
}
```

Looking at the console, the error: `GET https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token 401 (Unauthorized)` is displayed

[image: Error]

Full image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MgNw.png

### Questions

What is wrong?

Step by step debugging, authentication is performed successfully!?! Why?

Answer (score 0):

The `GET /oauth/access_token` is being requested twice. One succeeds and the other doesn't. It is probably getting the `401` because the `request_token` is only valid once. If you stop it from executing twice it should be fine.

On a side note you are including `oauth_callback` even while getting an `access_token`. This is not preferred.

Comment: In the case of an error, the system tries again. 401 occurs in two calls (in the first and second attempt).

Comment: I was getting a 200 the second attempt. What you might be running into is replication lag in Twitter's infrastructure. You authorize a request_token on one server and the request to get an access_token hits a different server that doesn't realize it has been authorized. Try adding a five second timeout before getting the access_token.